# Pure MVVM Without Code Behind

Tags: mvvm

I'm interested in approaches that avoids code in the code behind.
In my opinion, there are some cases where code must be placed in the code behind.
For example: I have a grid with an undefined count of columns. Columns can't be binded. So the easiest way would be to generate the columns in the code behind.

For this case, I can create a new class which inherits from the grid. This new class has a new binding property and code for the column binding. The code is separated in a custom class which can be used in the XAML. And then, I can easy bind the columns to my newly created property. And the view has no code behind.

Is it a good idea? How would you solve such (or similar) problems? 
Are there other ways to extract the code from the code behind?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use whichever tool makes the task simple.  There's nothing at all wrong with writing code... seriously.

Comment: In my opinion.. it IS! When I decided to work with MVVM I don't want to mix. Only code behind.... or only mvvm.. but no mix. I think this  is important.

Comment: Why do you think that is important?

Comment: Code-behind has its purposes, you know. MVVM doesn't mean no code-behind. It means removing code from the code-behind that shouldn't be there.

Comment: For example, when someone creates and application and you have to maintain it. If you have for example 70% in viewmodels and 30% code in code behind it's harded for you get into the application. Because it's not "standardized". You don't know where the code is. 
But this is not the question I asked. :)

Comment: @BoltClock: As I said: "there are some cases where code must be placed in the code behind." For example all UI specific code. But I think it must be still a better way than write the code direct into your code-behind. (Like I described: Control extension etc.)

Comment: *"70% in viewmodels and 30% code in code behind it's harded for you get into the application."* - Sounds to me like an uninformed assumption.  I have no problem reading code, no should any software developer. MVVM is about separating the presentation from the logic.  That doesn't mean the logic goes away entirely.  This all sounds very dogmatic.  each situation is different, you do your best to create a maintainable application given your requirements.

Comment: Yes it is just an assumption.

Answer (score 3):

Having a code behind free xaml.cs and moving to code to a new class does not mean its pure MVVM. The idea is you will have all the logic in ViewModel hence a code behind free View, helping in Unit Testing. View specific logic like colors and animation cannot be unittested hence doesnt matter where it resides, in an custom control or a inherited control or directly in xaml.cs. As long as you are testing most of the user interactions and view logic via UnitTesting, you should be happy that you have done a good job.

Comment: Yes I know. But I think you have a better MVVM support when you extend controls for your specific purposes. (For example the additional property for column binding). You can directly bind to this.

If you have a big view and you have to write a lot of code-behind (for example because of some limitations like column binding) the code will be unreadable.

(I'm not against code that has to be written in code behind. I just think it must be a better solution for this. Control extension or some other "patterns" whatever for handling this code better.